# Flutter: create custom widget from extended widget

Tags: flutter, widget, extends

How do create a custom widget that extends an already existing widget so it has the same parameters but with some different defaults?

```dart
class CustomRaisedButton extends RaisedButton {
  final ShapeBorder shape;
  final double elevation;

  CutstomRaisedButton({this.shape = RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)), this.elevation = 16})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should should create a custom stateless widget that returns your desired button. Pass along an 'OnPressed' function so you can handle the button press on the main page!

```
class CustomRaisedButton extends StatelessWidget {
   CustomRaisedButton({this.onPressed});

   final Function onPressed;

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return RaisedButton(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25)),
           elevation: 16,
           onPressed: onPressed,
       );
    }
}
```